# Multiple for loops to create a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I am trying to create a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
          -5      0      5
index                     
-5       NaN  slope  slope
 0     slope    NaN  slope
 5     slope  slope    NaN
```

but the closest I can get is the code below which returns a dataframe with only one column (which is the list from the last iteration through the ctr1 loop)

```
weather = np.linspace(-5, 5, 3)

for ctr1 in weather:
    slope_list = []
    X1 = round(ctr1,1)
    for ctr2 in weather:
        X2 = round(ctr2,1)

        Y1 = regressor[0] * X1**3 + \
        regressor[1] * X1**2 + \
        regressor[2] * X1 + \
        regressor[3] 

        Y2 = regressor[0] * X2**3 + \
        regressor[1] * X2**2 + \
        regressor[2] * X2 + \
        regressor[3]

        slope = (Y2-Y1)/(X2-X1)
        slope_list.append(slope)

    df_final = pd.DataFrame({X1:slope_list})
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please provide expected output.

Comment: Hi andrew_reece, the expected output is as I have shown right at the top where each 'slope' is a number (based on the calculation using X1, X2, Y1, Y2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try directly assign values in DataFrame. Just create empty DataFrame with index=weather:

```
import numpy as np
weather = np.linspace(-5, 5, 3)
df_final = pd.DataFrame([], index=weather)
for ctr1 in weather:
    X1 = round(ctr1,1)
    for ctr2 in weather:
        X2 = round(ctr2,1)

        Y1 = regressor[0] * X1**3 + \
        regressor[1] * X1**2 + \
        regressor[2] * X1 + \
        regressor[3] 

        Y2 = regressor[0] * X2**3 + \
        regressor[1] * X2**2 + \
        regressor[2] * X2 + \
        regressor[3]

       slope = (Y2-Y1)/(X2-X1)

       df_final.loc[X1, X2] = np.NaN if X1 == X2 else slope
```

Comment: For integer positional setting, I recommend you use the more efficient `.iat` instead of `.loc`.

Comment: Hi Alexey, thank you for your solution. For completeness, I thought I would provide the only update I needed to add for it to work perfectly for a larger weather array. I have added my own solution based mostly on your code.

Answer (score 2):

df_final is getting only 3 elements because it's at the same indentation level as `for ctr2 in weather`, so it's getting reassigned every outer loop. Although, if you fix that, you'll get a dataframe that's only a single long column: you only have a single `slope_list` getting appended to that turns into a dataframe at the end.

This is how I would solve that without changing your assignment method:

```
weather = np.linspace(-5, 5, 3)
slope_list = []
for ctr1 in weather:
X1 = round(ctr1,1)
for ctr2 in weather:
    X2 = round(ctr2,1)

    Y1 = regressor[0] * X1**3 + \
    regressor[1] * X1**2 + \
    regressor[2] * X1 + \
    regressor[3] 

    Y2 = regressor[0] * X2**3 + \
    regressor[1] * X2**2 + \
    regressor[2] * X2 + \
    regressor[3]

    slope = (Y2-Y1)/(X2-X1)
    slope_list.append(slope)


#make it 3 columns and 3 rows as intended
slope_list = np.array(slope_list).reshape(3, 3)
#make the dataframe
df_final = pd.DataFrame({X1:slope_list})
#manually add the desired row and column indexes
df_final = df.set_index(weather)
df_final.columns = weather
```

Although you should keep in mind that unless you know exactly what you're doing, making loops and nested loops when working with pandas usually means you're missing a much easier and better way to go about things.

Answer (score 0):

`slope_list = []` resets resulting list at each iteration, so just the last one remains. You need to define result list outside the outer loop, and append subresults to it.

Comment: Thanks Kosist, the reason I reset slope_list inside the outer loop is because I only want each column to have 3 rows. If I set it outside the outer loop, I end up with a list with 9 values.

Comment: Could you post `regressor` data also (better then full code), so we could try to run the code? B/c now you reset data by this, and that's why there is just one column with the last ctr1 iteration.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, for completeness, I have posted an answer to my question that works with a larger weather array. The only difference is that I did the rounding earlier in the code:

```
weather = np.round(np.linspace(-5, 35, 401), decimals = 1)
df_final = pd.DataFrame([], index=weather)
for ctr1 in weather:
    X1 = ctr1
    for ctr2 in weather:
        X2 = ctr2

        Y1 = regressor[0] * X1**3 + \
        regressor[1] * X1**2 + \
        regressor[2] * X1 + \
        regressor[3] 

        Y2 = regressor[0] * X2**3 + \
        regressor[1] * X2**2 + \
        regressor[2] * X2 + \
        regressor[3]

        slope = (Y2-Y1)/(X2-X1)

        df_final.loc[X1, X2] = np.NaN if X1 == X2 else slope
```